# Border around vert scroll div

Tags: html, css

I have a top div and under it a div that is full height and scrolls vertically with the scroll bar hidden. This works :)

```css
 #top_bar {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
 }
 #main_mask {
     width: 60%;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }
 #main_scroll {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     padding-right: 17px;
     -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
     box-sizing: content-box;
 }
 #content {
     /*height: 100%*/
 }
```

```html
<div id="top_bar">
   Top bar
</div>
<div id="main_mask">
   <div id="main_scroll">
      <div id="content">
         This is some variable content
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have `#content` be full height under `#top_bar`.

I cannot put the border on `#main_mask` or `#main_scroll` as everything is stepped in the right hand side so it looks uneven.

When I place a border for `#content` it is less than page height when there is little content and if I make it `height:100%` then it chops off content on long pages when I scroll...

Comment: not able to get what you are trying. can you share a image to say what you are trying?

Comment: I just want a box in the middle with content that is bordered and can be scrolled vertically without the vert scroll bar being visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure `body` and `html` has `height: 100%`, then make `#main_mask` height to be `calc(100% - 50px)` where `50px` is the height of `#top_bar`. Also give `box-sizing: border-box` to which you are giving `border`, here it is `#content`

what do you mean by **border around it that lines up the edges of `#top_bar.`**

```css
 body, html {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
 #top_bar {
     width: 60%;
     height: 50px;
 }
 #main_mask {
     width: 60%;
     height: calc(100% - 50px);
     overflow: hidden;
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }
 #main_scroll {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     padding-right: 17px;
     -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
     box-sizing: content-box;
 }
 #content {
     min-height: 100%;
     overflow: auto;
     border: 1px solid;
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<div id="top_bar">
   Top bar
</div>
<div id="main_mask">
   <div id="main_scroll">
      <div id="content">
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
         This is some variable content
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good however the vert scroll bar is visible which I do not wish to see.

Comment: Don't worry about aligning with the top bar edges. I will update the qn to make top_bar width: 100%

Comment: you mean `content` should have `min-height` till the end of page and extend its height if content extends ?

Comment: then instead of `height:100%` give `min-height:100%` to `#content`

Comment: or you just want the scrollbar to hide ?

Comment: `::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}` use this to hide the scrollbar

Comment: Yes, min-height worked. So simple... Let me test a bit more first and if all good please update answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be helpful.

```
#content {
padding: 5px 10%;
border: 1px solid #999;
text-align:center;
height: 100%
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vqpL0w5n/1/

Comment: I can't open the fiddle. Maybe wrong link? https://jsfiddle.net/vqpL0w5n/1/

Comment: can you please check the link now?

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting output like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/gk3azmLj/1/

```css
#top_bar {
     width: 60%;
     height: 50px;
     margin:auto;
     background:wheat;
     border:1px solid blue;
 }
 #main_mask {
     width: 60%;
     overflow: hidden;
     display: block;
     margin:auto;
 }
 #main_scroll {
     width: 100%;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
     box-sizing: content-box;
 }
 #content {
     height: 100vh;
     width:100%;
     background:white;
 }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
  background: transparent; 
 }

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: #FF0000;
 }
```

```html
<div id="top_bar">
   Top bar
</div>
<div id="main_mask">
   <div id="main_scroll">
      <div id="content">
         This is some variable content
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to vert scroll bar to be hidden.